# How to invoke the subscribed method using separate thread in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

```
SpreadsheetUserControl.SPlusSpreadsheetControl.Drop += AttributeControl_Drop;
```

`AttributeControl_Drop;` needs to be called in a separate thread

I have no idea, need help with this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

An event handler will be executed on the same thread as the event is raised on. If you have code that needs to be executed on a thread other than the one on which the event was raised, you have to do that inside the event handler.

The thing is, it's bad practice to expose a child control publicly from a user control in the first place, so this:

```cs
SpreadsheetUserControl.SPlusSpreadsheetControl.Drop
```

shouldn't even be possible. If you have control of that user control, you should make that child control private and then provide a pass-through event. That means that you would handle that `Drop` event on the UI thread within the user control and then raise your own event, which could be done on a secondary thread if appropriate.

Having said all that, if the code you want to execute interacts with the UI then you shouldn't and possibly can't do it on any other thread anyway.